# How to get value through xpath for repeating tags,it's like key value pair

Tags: java, xpath

I am developing very dynamic application. I have the below xml as input request.I am querying below through xpath.For example ,I have to get the perticular value of UpdateTime.how can i write the xpath to get the value of this field.The problem is the order of AdditionalData tag can be change.

What can i put the logic here...?

```
<InputData>
  <AdditionalData>
    <Name>TransmissionDatetime</Name>
    <Value>20101130121706</Value>
  </AdditionalData>
  <AdditionalData>
    <Name>UpdateDate</Name>
    <Value>20101130121604</Value>
  </AdditionalData>
  <AdditionalData>
    <Name>TimeofArrival</Name>
    <Value>20101130161705</Value>
  </AdditionalData>
  <AdditionalData>
    <Name>Part</Name>
    <Value>20101130161236</Value>
  </AdditionalData>
  <AdditionalData>
    <Name>SiteID</Name>
    <Value>1520537</Value>
  </AdditionalData>
</InputData>
```

Can any one help me and give some idea.....???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't made the requirement very clear, but I suspect you are looking for

```
/InputData/AdditionalData[Name='UpdateDate']/Value
```

Answer (score 1):

try this: `/InputData/AdditionalData[Name='UpdateDate']` ?

have a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: Hmm... I wasn't aware w3schools was so bad. Check out [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com/). So tempted not to upvote your comment for not giving any explanation why w3schools would merit a downvote ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For a xpath test and development tool try [XPathVisualizer](http://XPathVisualizer.codeplex.com)...

[image]

Free. Windows only, uses .NET