# Searching for XML Data in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, xquery

I have a XML column in a database with the following

```
<SelectedValues haveDefaultsBeenSet="true">
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>Item Condition</Name>
    <Value>New</Value>
    <ValueID>1000</ValueID>
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>Brand</Name>
    <Value>Sony</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>MPN</Name>
    <Value>8</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>Model</Name>
    <Value>DVD</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>MFR</Name>
    <Value>Sony</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>PackQuantity</Name>
    <Value>3</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
</SelectedValues>
```

I'm trying to return the Value when the name matches MFR. So when I'm searching for MFR I'M looking for result Sony

I have tried this

```
SELECT Itemspecifics.value('(/SelectedValues/SelectedValue/Value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as MFR
FROM [SixBit_BT].[dbo].[ItemsEbay]
Where itemspecifics.exist('//.[text()="MFR"]') = 1
```

Which does work to show only results that have MFR in the XML column, but it gives me the first value in this case 'New'. If i change the [1] to [5]. I do get the correct result for this example but it is not always in that position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My xpath is a little rusty but I think you want something like this:

`'(/SelectedValues/SelectedValue[Name="MFR"]/Value)[1]'`

Or maybe just this since it should give you a single item

`'/SelectedValues/SelectedValue[Name="MFR"]/Value'`

Here is a similar xpath example for little sanity check, since I'm not in a position to test this myself at the moment:
[How to get value through xpath for repeating tags,it's like key value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034571/how-to-get-value-through-xpath-for-repeating-tags-its-like-key-value-pair)

Answer (score 0):

Your code just select the first `Value` node, not the first one that matches "MFR". Use this instead:

```
SELECT Itemspecifics.query('//SelectedValue[Name = "MFR"]/Value').value('.[1]','varchar(max)')
FROM [SixBit_BT].[dbo].[ItemsEbay]
Where itemspecifics.exist('//.[text()="MFR"]') = 1
```